# Python Pandas: How do I get data one for each nth line with CSV files in?

Tags: python, pandas

The data file is so big that I want to receive it at certain intervals only to reduce the interpretation time. I'm using pandas.read_csv. How can I get only one line for every n lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ignoring rows by their indices:

```
n = 5
skip_func = lambda x: x%n != 0
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows = skip_func)
```

When `skiprows` is a callable, `pandas.read_csv` ignore those rows whose indices return `True` when they are evaluated in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Not the every nth row but if the dataset is huge you can try to read and process it in chunks like that:

```
df_chunks = pd.read_csv("train/train.csv", chunksize=5000)
```

In this case it will return not the whole data frame but an iterator, each contains some portion of the csv file with 5000 rows.